# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to promisify my mysql pool connection so that I can use the `await`  keyword.

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const util = require('util')

//Need this package for windows authentication
require('msnodesqlv8');


let config;
console.log(keys)
if (keys.db.state.toLowerCase() == "dev") {
    config = {
        user: keys.db.dev_user,
        password: keys.db.dev_password,
        server: keys.db.dev_server, // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
        database: keys.db.dev_database,
        // driver:'msnodesqlv8',
        pool: {
            max: 10,
            min: 5,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
        },
        options: {
            encrypt: false,
            instanceName: keys.db.dev_instanceName,
            enableArithAbort: true
        },
        //  port:57909,
        enableArithAbort: false
    }
} 

console.log(config)

let pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect()
    .then(query => {
        return query
    })
    .catch(e => console.error("Database Trouble!  ", e))

pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query)

module.exports = pool;
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of
> type function. Received undefined

I do not understand how we are receiving undefined when I am returning query after connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is the util.promisify() method failing?

The *pool* variable is a pending promise.  Therefore, *pool.query* is undefined until the promise is resolved.

### How to use await?

Since the *connect()* method returns a promise, you already can.  You need to resolve the connect promise and then *pool* will have a *query()* method that also returns a promise.

For example:

```js
...

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
(async function () {
    await pool.connect();
    const result = await pool.query('A QUERY HERE');
})()
```